# Angular Dialog requires extra mouse click to open when using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-changedetection

I have an Angular component that utilises the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy. When I attempt to open this component within a dialog using dialog.open(), I have to perform an additional mouse click to successfully open the modal. However, if I remove the ChangeDetectionStrategy and leave it as the default, the dialog opens as expected.

Why does this issue occur, and how can I fix it while keeping the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy?

Here's an example of my code, this is the main component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Dialog closed');
    });
  }
}
```

And here's the dialog component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialog',
  template: `
    <h1>Dialog Content</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the dialog.</p>
    <button mat-button (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyDialogComponent {
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>) {}

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

What could be causing this behaviour and how can I resolve it? Thank you for any help or insights you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Manually invoking the `detectChanges()` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` class can be used to trigger change detection and update the component's view even when using the "OnPush" change detection strategy.

```
export class MyComponent {
   //If you are using angular 14+ inject function can be used to resolve deps.
   //private cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);
   constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Dialog closed');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, however, it still doesn't work and requires an extra click to open the modal

Comment: can you please create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Use ‘this.cdr.detectChanges();’ as mentioned already to trigger the change manually but in order to run it only when needed thus keeping the opitmization benefits of the OnPush strategy, use a guard like ‘is Open’ and only trigger the detection if the value is false.

Comment: I tried adding it, however, it doesn't really do anything. Could you provide a sample code to show how to do it properly?

Comment: Let me know if this is working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rnhtui?file=src%2Fmain.ts